# Devextreme dxo-item-dragging: error any method call from method onDragEnd

Tags: html, angular, typescript, drag, devextreme

I cannot access any value in typescript inside the function triggered by the onAdd event of the dxo-item-dragging element. All come undefined

HTML Code :

```
<dxo-item-dragging group="'server'" [data]="tasks"
                [allowReordering]="true" [onDragStart]="onDragStart" [onAdd]="onAdd" [onRemove]="onRemove">
              </dxo-item-dragging>
```

TS Code:

```
onAdd(e) {
    e.toData.splice(e.toIndex, 0, e.itemData);
    let a = this.tasks;
  }
```

When I do let a = this.tasks, this.tasks comes as undefined. Actually I defined it.
When I type [onAdd]="onAdd.bind(this)" instead of [onAdd]="onAdd", I can access all properties, but this time the ui slows down a lot and freezes.

Thanks in advance for your help

I tried binding the event event to a function.
I was expecting to access all properties in that function, but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

in the example in this link https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/DnDBetweenGrids/Angular/Light/ there is a solution to my problem. For those who have the same problem as me, the solution to my problem is to put

```
this.onAdd = this.onAdd.bind(this);
```

It was enough for me to write. Have a nice day